# Java - Correctly Removing an Image to avoid Memory Leaks

Tags: java, memory-leaks, bufferedimage

As the title suggests, I'm getting memory leaks and I suspect their origin lies within the creation of new images. The memory leak is of type **java.util.Hashtable$Entry**. Google searches haven't provided me with anything relating to image creation.

The project is an interpolator - the user inputs a number of points and the program joins them together with curves. When this is done, the curves are drawn on an image. This necessitates that each time the interpolation is generated, the image is recreated with the new width and height before it's drawn over.

I believe that I've narrowed down the leak to this method:

```
public void reset(int width, int height){
    if (width >= 15){
        i_width = width;
    } else {
        i_width = 15;
    }
    if (height >= 15){
        i_height = height;
    } else { 
        i_height = 15;
    }

    try {
        image.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    image = new BufferedImage(i_width, i_height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    graphics = image.createGraphics();
    Color color = new Color(1f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
    graphics.setColor(color);
    for(int y = 0; y < i_height; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < i_width; x++){
            graphics.fillRect((x), (y), 1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Above, *image* is the BufferedImage I'm writing to whilst *graphics* is the Graphics2D instance. As you can probably guess, *i_width* and *i_height* represent the image's new width and height respectively.

I determined that this method is the main source since the leaks are only noticeable when it's called.

As you can see above, I've tried flushing the *image*, and in another section I also disposed of the *graphics*. That is as far as I managed, unfortunately, and it didn't solve the memory leak problem.

How should I avoid this memory leak?

Comment: I would double check that you're "disposing" of the graphics correctly.

Comment: Where is the HashMap being used?  What types of objects are being put in there?

Comment: The HashMap isn't my own - I assume it has something to do with the BufferedImage and is being used by the image.

Comment: @GeoffGenz double-checked:

`reset(new_width, new_height);
drawInterpolation();
graphics.dispose();`

Comment: Any way to create an example where the problem can be reproduced?

Comment: @Marco13 I think that's what I'll have to do. I refrained from doing this earlier since this is a 77-page project.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem myself. Unfortunately I couldn't determine the **why** of the problem, but I could determine the **how** to the solution.

Basically what I did is the following:

1. Create the Graphics2D
2. Reset the image
3. Dispose of the Graphics2D
4. Create the Graphics2D
5. Draw the interpolation
6. Dispose of the Graphics2D

While there are still some memory leaks, they are very small (insignificant) and I don't believe they have anything to do with this issue.